# uninitialized constant BSON::InvalidObjectId Error for rack-gridfs gem

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rack, gridfs

I have some images stored in GridFs of Mongodb and I would like to get the url of the image. I installed rack-gridfs gem and here is the link to the gem: https://github.com/skinandbones/rack-gridfs/

I am currently using Rails 4.0.0 so I edited the config/routes.rb only as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  namespace :admin do
    resources :users do    
      resources :annotations
    end
    mount Rack::GridFS::Endpoint.new(:db =>Mongoid::Config.sessions[:default]), :at => "gridfs"
  end
end
```

But when I tried http://localhost:3000/admin/gridfs/54f5ece4e4b0e8f8dcce15d0, an error came up as "**uninitialized constant BSON::InvalidObjectId**". The same error came up when I tried http://localhost:3000/admin/gridfs. I got the id from the fs.files collection of the Mongodb.

Here is an example of an image in fs.files:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55314ad2e4b08b15f51ddf65"), "metadata" : { "_id" :  "ced7ca7f-e287-45b5-a58b-70b9f397a253", "media_id" : "2ED3539B-E62B-4EA1-8224-3EE0DA8386E8.jpg", "data_point_id" : "1A48F01F-725F-49FD-A2A2-347D71910693", "size" : NumberLong(354010), "content_type" : "image/jpeg"}, "filename" : "ced7ca7f-e287-45b5-a58b-70b9f397a253", "aliases" : null, "chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120), "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-04-17T18:02:58.880Z"), "length" : NumberLong(354010), "contentType" : "image/jpeg", "md5" : "e01669ddc1b26b48086ec1c700004f00" }
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you very much!!!